# Android In App Billing crashes only in Samsung tab 10.1

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I got a very strange problem when I'm testing the In App Billing. The app crashes only in Samsung tab 10.1 with the following error message which I totally have no clue what's wrong with it:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.d.b.a.b: Bad Base64 input character at 0: 5(decimal)
>
> ```
>    at com.test.iab.util.Security.verifyPurchase()
>    at com.test.iab.util.Security.verifyPurchase()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper$2.run()
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) Caused by: com.d.b.a.b: Bad Base64 input character at 0: 5(decimal)
>    at com.test.iab.util.Base64.decode4to3()
>    at com.test.iab.util.Base64.decode4to3()
>    at com.test.iab.util.Base64.decode4to3()
>    at com.test.iab.util.Security.verifyPurchase()
>    at com.test.iab.util.Security.verifyPurchase()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper.enableDebugLogging()
>    at com.test.iab.util.IabHelper$2.run()
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> ```

The app works fine in Samsung S4, HTC one and some other devices but only crashes in Samsung tab 10.1. Does anybody have experience the same issue? The reason why I ask here is because I don't have a samsung tablet for debugging.

**EDIT:**

The reason I didn't post the source code is because the source code is from google and I have no idea exactly which code cause the problem. Anyway here is the code possibly related to the problem:

```
public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
            return false;
        }

        PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
        return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the device not the android version (KitKat)?

Comment: Can you add the snippets of code that crashes at. with pointing to the line of code?

Comment: Nobody encountered this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to decoding of your public key (which you copied from Google Play).

I would suggest to change a bit Google's code, namely function:

```
public static byte[] decode(String s) throws Base64DecoderException {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    return decode(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Weak point here's `getBytes()` which supposed to translate your Base64 encoded string into byte array. `getBytes()` is using default system charset, which is for all Android devices is UTF-8.

[Probably there's a bug in Galaxy Tab 10.1 related to default charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273868/sencha-touch-openlayers-geoserver-wrong-encoding-on-devices-using-android-2-2). Please try to use explicit charset UTF-8 like:

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll have a try.

Comment: I'm too busy to test your code. But I thought your answer is reasonable although it's fine to use another open source code without problems. So I'll give your 50 points.